# checking for duplicates in link list

Tags: c++, linked-list

> ```
> bool isduplicate
>
> if(p==nullptr) {
>     p->next=q;
>     q->value=x;
>  }
>
>   while (p!=nullptr) {
>      p=p->next;
>   }
>   //arrived at NULL ptr
>     p->next=q;
>    q->value=x;
>    q->next=nullptr;
>
>    return q;
> }
> ```

Comment: did you debug and checked your pointers? where is it crashing and when? why do you mix `nullptr` and `NULL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is wrong. current does not equal runner at the start of your while loop, and nothing inside the while loop will ever make them equal each other. Eventually you're going to dereference a null pointer.

The correct logic is simpler than what you have. Try this

```
current = p;
while (current != nullptr)
{
    runner = current->next;
    while (runner != nullptr)
    {
        if (runner->value == current->value)
            return true;
        runner = runner->next;
    }
    current = current->next;
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have no checks for a null `current` (or `runner`) pointer in the inner loop, which probably means that sooner or later either is going to be null and then you do

```
if(runner->value == current->value)
```

or

```
current = current->next;
```

Dereferencing a null pointer is undefined behavior, and will most likely cause a crash.